# How to specify a maximum image size with get_serving_url

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Some pictures, not all, exceed the maximum *width* and *height* that I want.
Is there a way to specify the max image size with `get_serving_url()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, size is an optional 2nd argument on get_serving_url. You can specify an integer between 0 and 1600; if either the height or width exceed this, the image is resized down to fit.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html

Comment: Thanks! Are we sure that's a mazimum size and not a scaling i.e. that smaller picture won't get scaled up? Cheers

Comment: Correct, smaller images will not be scaled up.